# How to develop an app with in-app billing feature in a country which is not in the support list?

Tags: android, google-play, billing, in-app

I want to develop an app with android in-app billing feature. However, after I download the in-app billing example, and follow the instructions, I always get a dialog saying "the market billing service is not available at this time" when I run the app. I am in China, and China is not in the support country list. So regret!

However, I still want to develop my app. So is there any method so that I can continue developing my app with in-app billing and bypassing the country restriction? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

marketenabler can help you bypass the country restriction. although it seems that there still are problems with the latest Google Play Store's client.